# Three Notes Per String and the 7 Modes

Tags: modes

If the third position of the three notes per string G major scale is the B Phrygian mode, then how do I play that same mode all over the fretboard of the guitar?

Comment: You use more than three notes per string.

Comment: Do you know what makes a set of notes a mode specifically B Phrygian in this case? If not, that may be a better starting point.

Comment: The 3rd 'position' of 3nps G major scale isn't B Phrygian. It's B Phrygian because it's rooted on the 3rd note of G major.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment, but it's too complicated for just a text sentence, the fretboard picture is needed...

[image]

From the top the three-notes-per-string "boxes" are ionian (major scale), dorian, and phrygian.

The red dot represents the tonic of a major scale. In this case it's a `C` major scale. So, the red dot is `C`.

In the "ionian" box the first note, the lowest note, is the tonic, the red dot, the `C`.

Notice that in the "dorian" and "phrygian" boxes the lowest note of the box is *not* the red dot, not the tonic. If you use these boxes, and want to play in `C` major, you would want to make the red dot, the tonic, the main "target", not the lowest note of the box. Because you maintain `C` as the target, these boxes are only *superficially* dorian or phrygian. You wouldn't really be playing in `D` dorian or `E` phrygian, because you would keep to focus on the `C` to maintain `C` major as the key.

If you really wanted to make the so-called "phrygian" box a phrygian mode, then you need to change the tonic, you need to change the placement of the red dot. Like this...

[image]

If you take that phrygian mode and "move it all over the fretboard," like move it down to the third fret...

[image]

...you now have `G` phrygian. Or, if you related that back to a major scale it would be a mode (or rotation) of `E` flat major.

Now we can get back to your question...

> If the third position of the three notes per string G major scale is the B Phrygian mode, then how do I play that same mode [B phrygian] all over the fretboard of the guitar?

Do you really mean to ask: how to play `B` phrygian all over the fretboard?

Do you want to play in `G` major or `B` phrygian?

Do you want to change the tonic?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean to ask. How to play B phyrgian all over the fretboard.

Comment: The three note per string "box" patterns will be the same, but the tonic and other scale degrees will shift around. Look for a diagram like this https://discoverguitaronline.com/diagrams/17.png. Try searching 'three notes per string phrygian mode.'

Answer (score 0):

You don't play the 3 notes per string scale shape all over the fretboard anyway. It has one specific place for each key.

So, using Phrygian as the example, you could leave out the first two notes from G major, and start on the 3rd. Use all the remaining notes from G major, in their 3nps positions, and there you have it. Move everything up 2 frets and it's C♯ Phrygian, etc.